# Salesforce Communities in dev org

Tags: community

I need to create salesforce community in my dev org.can I do it for free? So far I have reached just here for enabling communities : http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/free-trial-pricing/communities.jsp .

If it's possible,please provide the steps for how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can create a community in a DE org.

Setup -> Customize -> Communities

[image]

Comment: can't find Setup -> Communities in my DE org.can you elaborate more? Thanks.

Comment: just added a screenshot. Do you see it now?